# How to get a pokemon to a place

Tags: pokemon-go

we're entering a raft race on a pokemon go themed raft.  Is there anyway we can get a pokemon to be either (a) on the raft with us or (b) at the start/end point of the race?   Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Pokemon spawn very randomly throughout the world, and it's not possible to directly affect spawns.

On that note, you can Incense your account and get Pokemon to show up, but only for the Incense'd account.

Alternatively, if there's a PokeStop at the start/end of the race, you can apply a Lure Patch to it, or ask someone to. Note that a Lure Patch will expire after 30 minutes.

Finally, as pointed out by @Arperum, you can also start a battle and just "keep" the Pokemon on your screen until whenever you actually want to capture it.

Comment: You can. Just start a battle and then never catch the pokemon. It'll stay with you forever.

Comment: You have just made me the COOLEST mother of a 21 year old gamer EVER!!!!   thank you!!